# how to share variable between more than One file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

// app.js

```
var myvar = 1  
module.exports = {myvar};
```

// another in my project

```
var mynewvar =require("../app.js")
console.log(mynewvar.myvar); // undefined ?
```

I need to make var is global in all project ?
I'm try global but the same issue can any one help me?

Comment: Why are you exporting `lang` when your variable is called `myvar`?

Comment: i need To change value

Comment: i;m sorry edit no lang but myvar

Comment: console.dir(mynewvar)? You mis-spelled mynewvar in your question.

Comment: Why do you think it's not 'global'?  Node's module caching will make each require refer to the same module.

Comment: print  empty object like:    {}   @vicatcu

Comment: is not print value 1 in another file include my project @JimB.

Comment: Your code prints 1 as expected result, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Since you said it doesn't print value 1 in `another file`, why not show some code in the file that actually has a problem?

Comment: i'm try to declaration variable in global i need to change in value in some file include my project , not show all file is not important for you this is problem is actually seen in code above  @RicoChen

Comment: What is the directory structure of your project? What folders have the two files that you are asking about?

Comment: Are your unit dependencies circular by any chance?.   You called this file,. `app` to me that would indicate you call other units from this, if so your global vars might not have been initialized before use.  I would suggest placing your globals in there own unit with no dependencies.

Comment: is this full code https://ideone.com/G9BaSt

Comment: That link doesn't have all of the code you are depending on.  If I take out the dependencies it works.  I think, as others have suggested, you should have a separate module for your globals (globals.js?) and require that wherever you need those variables.

Comment: I solve it by another way using "app.locals.nameproperty"  in express is save value  in life cycle of application so this variable seeing  in all files in my project nodejs and I can edit form any were Thanks for all To help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is you might not have the path to app.js right.  This works:

```
// app.js

var myvar = 1  
module.exports = {myvar}; 

// index.js

var mynewvar =require("./app.js")
console.log(mynewvar.myvar);
```

Here's a repl.it that shows it works:

https://repl.it/repls/CruelMonstrousArchives

Maybe you're doing something different than this?

Comment: hhhhh nice Its work but in my project not work i need to Reread my code again thank you @JimB. Code-Appprentice

Comment: FYI, the policy of posting content here directly is a safeguard against broken links

Comment: Makes sense.  Right on.

Comment: I'm  so sorry I found the problem some mistake by Call  for example above  I'm calling run app.js not index.js in "nodemon app.js" command

Answer (score 1):

you can easily achieve this, either in es6(lib.js) way or es5(lib2.js) way.

live example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/mo8z2ooovj

export module es6 lib.js :

```
const myvar = 1;
export default myvar;`
```

export module es5 lib2.js :

```
var myvar2 = 2;
module.exports = myvar2;`
```

into another file you can import the modules and display the values like so, i use a component:

```
 import myvar from "./lib";
 import myvar2 from "./lib2";

 // you can use the imported values here as you need


 // e.g.
 function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
       <p>value from lib.js {myvar}</p>
       <p>value from lib2.js {myvar2}</p>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);`
```

Comment: This code example looks more complex than necessary for this question.

Comment: Thanks You! @Theo Itzaris

Comment: Hi @Emadjoha, if my answer helped you, please accept it as correct, so that other people that have similar issues could be helped too.